# Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException Maven Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am getting and error while running jmeter testscript via mvn .

Here is my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:pom:1.3.1</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:jar:0.10</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:jar:2.3</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <junitLibraries>
                    <artifact>com.lazerycode.junit:junit-test:1.0.0</artifact>
                </junitLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
</dependencies>
```

Jmeter Log File :

> 2017/08/17 16:57:42 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
>   ---- Debugging information ----
>   message             : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
>   cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
>   cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
>   class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
>   required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
>   path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/hashTree/hashTree/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
>   line number         : 76

I tried every thing but still no success .

Here is console output of an error I am getting

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.2.0:configure (configure) on project jmeter-demo: Could not find artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following line to `jmeterExtensions` section of your pom.xml file:

```
<artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:pom:2.6</artifact>
```

The error you're getting is about missing [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) which lives in [jmeter-plugins-json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-json) Maven artifact

More information:

- [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Hi I added that , but now I am getting different error :   Could not find artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1 in central